# Packaging a shoes app standalone (as exe)

Tags: ruby, windows, exe, shoes

I have a shoes app, packaged as a .shy file. This is a good way to distribute my program, but it requires the person using my app to have installed both ruby and shoes previously. That is not good, because my target users are not necessarily experienced with installing extra programs and don't necessarily understand that some programs depend on others. Is there a way to package my entire app as a .exe file, which does *not* require the separate installation of shoes, but instead packages it with my app?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to look into [Crate](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/crate) or [Ocra](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables)

Comment: Doesn't Shoes have it's own packager? But regardless, Ocra is what I've been recommended by other people, whether it works with Shoes or not is something you'd have to try. Certain resources say it should work, others say it doesn't (yet).

Comment: the shoes packager packages in a format that must be run through shoes. I want users of my app to not have to install shoes seperately

Comment: Ocra doesn't seem to work with `green_shoes` ruby gem